# unittest discover garbage collection?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, sqlalchemy

It looks like garbage collection is a problem with `python3 -m unittest discover`.

Look at this example:

file: **model.py** # a basic SQLAlchemy declarative model, as well as the DB manager to insert the data

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'model'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String, unique=True)
    val = Column('val', Integer)



class DBManager:
    
    def __init__(self, dbfile):
        self.engine = create_engine(f'sqlite:///{dbfile}')
        Base.metadata.create_all(bind=self.engine)

    def insert_into_db(self, data):
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        session = Session()
        for model in data:
            session.add(model)
        session.commit()
        session.close()
```

file: **creator.py** # it creates a single model and put it into a sqlite database

```
from model import Model

class ModelCreator:

    data = []

    def add_data(self, dic):
        self.data.append(Model(**dic))

    def get_data(self):
        if self.data:
            return self.data
        else:
            raise RuntimeError('No data found')
```

Now the tests (2 separate `unittest.TestCase` files with one test each)

file: **test_model.py**

```
import unittest
from creator import ModelCreator

class TestModelCreator(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self):
        self.mc = ModelCreator()


    def test_add_data(self):
        with self.assertRaises(RuntimeError):
            self.mc.get_data()
        d = {'name': 'model_test', 'val': 1}
        self.mc.add_data(d)
        self.assertEqual(len(self.mc.get_data()), 1)

    def tearDown(self):
        return super().tearDown()
```

file: **test_creator.py**

```
import unittest
import os
from model import DBManager
from creator import ModelCreator


class TestDB(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.dbfile = './test.db'

    def setUp(self):
        self.dbm = DBManager(self.dbfile)
        self.mc = ModelCreator()

    def test_insert_into_db(self):
        d = {'name': 'model_test', 'val': 1}
        self.mc.add_data(d)
        to_insert = self.mc.get_data()
        self.dbm.insert_into_db(to_insert)

    def tearDown(self):
        return super().tearDown()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        os.remove(cls.dbfile)
```

Each test runs smoothly when launched separately.

```
$ python3 -m unittest test_model.py 
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK

$ python3 -m unittest test_creator.py 
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.014s

OK
```

**BUT**

```
$ python3 -m unittest discover .
.F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_add_data (test_model.TestModelCreator)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marco/sw/temp/sqlalchemytest/test_model.py", line 12, in test_add_data
    self.mc.get_data()
AssertionError: RuntimeError not raised

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.013s

FAILED (failures=1)

$ nosetests -vw .
test_insert_into_db (test_creator.TestDB) ... ok
test_add_data (test_model.TestModelCreator) ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: test_add_data (test_model.TestModelCreator)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marco/sw/temp/sqlalchemytest/test_model.py", line 12, in test_add_data
    self.mc.get_data()
AssertionError: RuntimeError not raised

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.128s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

After a couple of `print` statements across the tests I found that maybe it is a problem of garbage collection.
So, my question is: how to enforce this?

Looks like the `tearDown` methods do not work properly....

It looked [solved](https://bugs.python.org/issue11798) in Python 3.4. Also, same problem was discusses (with no luck) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41594525/different-unittest-execution-result-with-and-without-using-unittest-discover) back in the days.

Now I'm using Python 3.9.2

Looking forward for any comments.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure garbage collection is the issue here.  `ModelCreator.data` is a class attribute, so all instances of `ModelCreator` share the same list.  The list will only be "cleared" if the  `creator` module is removed from `sys.modules` and reimported (or possibly if the module is reloaded).  Or if you clear it manually.

Comment: If you want `ModelCreator.data` to be garbage collected, make it an instance variable by doing `self.data = []` in `ModelCreator.__init__`.

Comment: @snakecharmerb this was the right solution! Thank you very much.

Comment: More or less. Quoting: "Class attributes become instance attributes if and only if a value is assigned to them after instantiation, being in the `__init__` method or not". Then I don't get why `unittest discover` does not clean instance attributes set in that way. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: If you assign to a class var at instance level it will override the class var in the instance's `__dict__`,  for example `instance.data = [1, 2, 3]`.  But if you mutate the class var - `instance.data.append(1)` - the class var is mutated.  Your code is mutating, not assigning, so there is no instance attribute to clear.  Compare the contents of the class and instance `__dict__` to see what is happening.

Comment: I see it, now. Thank you very much!